# Application built using Eclipse crashes when running

Tags: boost, boost-asio, eclipse-cdt

I have written simple TCP client application using boost libraries on windows , I used Eclipse Kepler and minGW C++ compiler .. it builds well but when I run the program via eclipse it crashes suddenly .. I set all the path of boost in my elcipse . i.e includes,libs,libname of boost libs in the eclipse .

all my boost libs are static libs.
Libraries I added :

```
 ws2_32
 boost_system-mgw46-mt-1_53
 Mswsock
```

Let me know how to run that application now?

Comment: Does it not crash when you run it outside of Eclipse? "it crashes suddenly" Does this mean there is a segmentation fault somtime into execution or does it not start at all? In the first case, have you debugged your code?

Comment: I am trying inside eclipse only ..It will not at all start .. I am printing in the start of the application itself(before starting anything). it throws the error testtcpcleint.exe stoped working .. I am running in debug mode

Comment: There is the symbol of a bug in the upper toolbar. Click it and the debugger will start. If it asks you to open the debug perpective agree. Then click F8 and it will show you the line in your code that causes the error. Then post that code and the stack trace (upper left window part). Alternatively post your full code if it is not too long. (Reduce it if it is)